# Trying to use separate style in different activities, but not working its unfortunately stopped

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm using one TableLayout which is using style which is not functioning for different activities in same application

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">#11a40f</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00a8e6</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#1574c7</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

styles.xml

```
<resources>

 <style name="AppThemeOne" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">#11a40f</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00a8e6</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#1574c7</item>
</style>

 <style name="AppThemeTwo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">#11a40f</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00a8e6</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#1574c7</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/title_activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeTwo">

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AbcActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeOne">
        </activity>
```

Comment: actually i'm using this already. I have one another activity ... when I am setting  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> then the lablaout is stopped working bcoz its need NoActionbar what should i do